# Disable listbox Vertical Scrollbar in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i wondering how to disable the listbox scrollbar.Because i already have a scroll bar which can control both textbox scroll together at the same time. As i know,For Horizontal just add the width, how about vertical scroll bar without changing any height value?
This is  inherent for listbox property,but anyway to change it? Thanks for help.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Which listbox - Forms or ActiveX ?

Comment: Forms in userform using vba excel

Comment: Not sure it's possible with a forms control.

Comment: @TimWilliams: It's I believe ActiveX Control on a form.

Comment: @whywhy: Usually the API should work but it is not working in this case. I am still experimenting. One other alternative is to put the listboxes in individual frames and reduce the width of the frame so that it hides the scrollbar.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - yes: it's getting too late for me!  I did try a couple API examples but none of them worked.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I couldn't find any apis examples so I wrote one from scratch but it still is not working and I am simply surprised!!!

Comment: @SiddharthRout - seems like MSForms controls are "Windowless" and so cannot be manipulated like the windowed equivalents.

Comment: @TimWilliams: They have handles if that is what you mean. See the code in answer below.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Maybe I am missing something very simple... I just got up and haven't had the time for my morning cup of coffee. This question was too tempting :P

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt property that you can use to hide the scrollbars.

Usually the APIs work but in this case it is not working. The logic is to get the handle of the listbox and then hide the scrollbar. For example

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function ShowScrollBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal wBar As Long, ByVal bShow As Long) As Long

Private Const SB_HORZ = 0 '<~~ Horizontal Scrollbar
Private Const SB_VERT = 1 '<~~ Vertical Scrollbbar
Private Const SB_BOTH = 3 '<~~ Both ScrollBars

Dim lngMyHandle As Long, ChildRet As Long
Dim i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 1 To 100
        ListBox1.AddItem i
        ListBox2.AddItem i
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    lngMyHandle = FindWindow("THUNDERDFRAME", Me.Caption)

    If lngMyHandle <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Found Userform's handle"

    ChildRet = FindWindowEx(lngMyHandle, ByVal 0&, "F3 Server 516c0000", vbNullString)

    If ChildRet <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Found Listbox's Handle"

    '~~> I Found the listbox Handle but it REFUSES TO WORK!!!
    ShowScrollBar ChildRet, SB_BOTH, False
End Sub
```

I used spy++ to get the class of the listbox as shown below and in the code above I do get the value of `ChildRet` but I was disappointed. For the first time I am having a difficulty to understand as to why the API's are not working and I will continue experimenting with it.

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE**

Having said that there is an alternative. Place the Listbox in individual frames and reduce the width of the frame so that it hides the scrollbar. See this example

[image]

This is the most simplest way I could think of.

Comment: i tried your method,but the scrollbar still shown although i add the individual frames for each listbox. Width Frame < Listbox still the same.

Comment: @whywhy. The above screenshot is at runtime. Are you sure the listbox is inside the frame?

Comment: when i put my listbox inside the frame,the frame block my listbox content when i run it.

Comment: @whywhy: Show me your file. you may upload it in www.wikisend.com and share the link here

Comment: Thanks Siddharth Rout !!  i got error because of my listbox width small than frame. Solved :)